# Convert UNIX timestamp to .NET DateTime ticks in unmanaged code (without using .NET)

Tags: .net, datetime, unix-timestamp

I need to "construct" .NET DateTime values in Python/C++.

How can I compute the number of ticks stored by DateTime starting from a UNIX timestamp?

A solution involving Win32 API calls it's ok (I believe FILETIME functions could help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you the number of ticks since that the Unix Epoc starts at (which is 621,355,968,000,000,000)

```
(new DateTime( 1970,1,1) - DateTime.MinValue).Ticks
```

This gives you ticks per second (which is 10,000,000)

```
TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond
```

Just math from there (may run into weirdness around leap seconds).

Comment: TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond Field -- The value of this constant is 10 thousand; that is, 10,000.

Comment: TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond Field -- The value of this constant is 10 million; that is, 10,000,000.

Comment: TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute Field -- The value of this constant is 600 million; that is, 600,000,000.

Comment: @amissico: That's great, but Unix time is number of seconds since since 1/1/1970, why would he need higher tick resolution (like TicksPerMillisecond)?

Comment: At the time I was looking up this information. I just added it because I was updating my development notes, and figured I would save someone some time down the road.

Comment: thanks! searching for 621355968000000000 yields interesting results